# uninitialized constant Like::ArticleId

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to create a simple blog app using rails based on tutorials [here](https://deallen7.medium.com/ruby-on-rails-app-build-blog-3d9975a999ae#529c) and [here](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-add-a-simple-like-button-to-your-rails-6-application-c1040999dc2). The code works fine from the first link but trying to add a like button to articles using the second tutorial I'm getting an 'uninitilized constant' error. The error throws out the following pieces of codes from the articles model and the articles show.html.erb.

article.rb:

```
    class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :likes
    validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 50 }
    validates :description, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 300 }
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    def liked?(user)
        !!self.likes.find{|like| like.user_id == user.id}
    end
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<h2 align="center">Title: <%= @article.title %></h2>
<div class="well col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
 <% if @article.user %>
 <ul class="listing">
  <div class="row" align="center">
   <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <li><%= link_to gravatar_for(@article.user), user_path(@article.user) %></li>
    <li class="article-title"><%= link_to @article.user.username, user_path(@article.user) %></li>
    <li><small><%= pluralize(@article.user.articles.count, "article") if @article.user.articles %></small></li>
   </div>
  </div>
 </ul> 
 <% end %>
 <h4 class="center description"><strong>Description:</strong></h4>
 <hr>
 <%= simple_format(@article.description) %>
 <div> <% if logged_in? %>
    <% if @article.liked?(current_user) %>
     <%= button_to "Like", like_path(@article), method: "put", disabled: true %>
     <% else %>
     <%= button_to "Like", like_path(@article), method: "put" %>
     <% end %>
     <% end %>
 </div>
```

It seems the issue lies here `!!self.likes.find{|like| like.user_id == user.id}` and `<% if @article.liked?(current_user) %>`. Can't seem to figure out the issue. I am using rails 5. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Here is the table (migrate):

```
class CreateLikes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :likes do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user_id, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :article_id, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The like model:

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user_id
  belongs_to :article_id
  validates :user_id, uniqueness: {scope: :article_id}
end
```

Comment: Doe your `likes` table have an `article_id` column? Can you please show the relevant parts of the `Like` model?

Comment: `Like::ArticleId` doesn't seem like something that'd be part of Rails' auto-magic; does it appear in your source somewhere?

Comment: Its hard to provide any answer without all the relevant information, like the Like model information and the migrations you used to create / associate the models etc..

Comment: Thats a really inefficient way of doing it - you want to do `self.likes.exist?(user_id: user.id)` instead of loading every row on the table.

Comment: I updated the post to include the like model and table.

Comment: It seems to go wrong with your `migration` and your `Like model`. You're referencing to `user_id` and `article_id` by using a `belongs_to` in the migration. And you're using a `belongs_t`o  `user_id` and `article_id` in the model as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to go wrong with your `migration` and your `Like model`. You're referencing to `user_id` and `article_id` by using a `belongs_to` in the migration. And you're using a `belongs_t`o  `user_id` and `article_id` in the model as well.

For the migration you could do the following:

```
class CreateLikes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :likes do |t|
      t.references :article, foreign_key: true
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And your model should look like this:

```
class Like < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :article
  validates :user_id, uniqueness: {scope: :article_id}
end
```

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian. I tried it and got a different error: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: likes.article_id: SELECT "likes".* FROM "likes" WHERE "likes"."article_id" = ?`

Comment: Actually, I needed a rollback and a db:migrate then it worked. Thanks.